# Felix OSGi embedded in Android: Starting SCR causes in Fatal Error generated in libc.so

Tags: android, osgi, libc

I have an android project (run on Sony Tablet SGP512 with Android 4.4.4, API 19) with Felix OSGi embedded. All bundles are dexified. I can install and start all bundles without errors except the Felix SCR (ServiceComponentRuntime). Installing works fine but to start this bundles causes in the following error and the app crashes:

```
06-06 17:09:47.741 27371-27371/android.cit.tu_berlin.de.helloandroid A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000021 (code=1), thread 27371 (de.helloandroid)
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? D/clmlib: Got activities:0x0000000E
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? I/DEBUG: UUID: 9fb4e970-7a78-4d74-a678-9eb7a2799b9e
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Sony/SGP512/SGP512:4.4.4/23.0.1.A.4.30/4e_3Rw:user/release-keys'
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? I/DEBUG: pid: 27371, tid: 27371, name: de.helloandroid  >>> android.cit.tu_berlin.de.helloandroid <<<
06-06 17:09:47.851 288-288/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000021
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     r0 6d4827a8  r1 00000073  r2 00000001  r3 71736f74
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     r4 719081e0  r5 6d478800  r6 414f3898  r7 0000206e
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     r8 41516540  r9 00000021  sl 00000002  fp 4219e6d4
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     ip 0000006e  sp bed3a4a8  lr 4154a8cb  pc 4151adb8  cpsr 200e0010
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d4  002100010020001f  d5  0002000200500000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d6  0100b72b2a100000  d7  b5022a0200b5022a
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d16 7265532f61746164  d17 6174654d65636976
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d18 00000000415db068  d19 44c085c044c08578
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d20 00000000415db068  d21 44c0866044c08600
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d22 00000000415db068  d23 44c0879844c086a8
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     scr 80000010
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 00024db8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 00030cec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 0002e384  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 000637bd  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 0006b78f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #05  pc 00029860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #06  pc 00030cec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #07  pc 0002e384  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #08  pc 000634d9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #09  pc 0004cc37  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #10  pc 0004e40b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #11  pc 0004f12f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #12  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #13  pc 0000e573  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #14  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG: stack:
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a468  414f3898  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a46c  4154e8a3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmReleaseTrackedAlloc+30)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a470  44c08ff8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a474  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a478  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a47c  41629cc8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a480  71733000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a484  41565701  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveString+42)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a488  44bcaaf0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a48c  00000004  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a490  71733038  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a494  719081dc  /data/data/android.cit.tu_berlin.de.helloandroid/cache/bundle3/version0.0/bundle.jar.dex
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a498  6d478800  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a49c  414f3898  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4a0  0000031a  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4a4  4151a550  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #00  bed3a4a8  00000926  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4ac  414f3898  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4b0  41526ca0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*))
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4b4  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4b8  bed3a598  [stack]
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4bc  414f3898  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4c0  bed3a4fc  [stack]
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4c4  6d560c28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4c8  4219e6d4  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4cc  41526cf0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+80)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #01  bed3a4d0  2f617661  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4d4  676e616c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4d8  7274532f  /system/framework/framework-res.apk
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4dc  3b676e69  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4e0  41005629  /system/lib/libLLVM.so (std::vector<llvm::MachineFrameInfo::StackObject, std::allocator<llvm::MachineFrameInfo::StackObject> >::_M_fill_insert_aux(llvm::MachineFrameInfo::StackObject*, unsigned int, llvm::MachineFrameInfo::StackObject const&, std::__false_type const&)+204)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4e4  fffffe58  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4e8  41526ca0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*))
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4ec  41524388  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+188)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     #02  bed3a4f0  00000050  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4f4  41c69008  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4f8  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a4fc  6ef31e24  /system/framework/framework.odex
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a500  6d478ec4  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a504  6d48a6d0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a508  6e79b000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a50c  4219e698  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a510  80c0e261  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a514  bed3a630  [stack]
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a518  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a51c  bed3a684  [stack]
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a520  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a524  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a528  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          bed3a52c  00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:          ........  ........
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r0:
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482788 00000f35 6e67dc2b 6e529c34 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482798 00000000 00000000 6e75c71c 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4827a8 415c50e0 00000101 00020001 00020000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4827b8 6e68a378 415c3de0 00000f20 6e67dc2b  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4827c8 00000000 70000000 4156086b 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4827d8 00000000 00000000 415c50e0 00000001  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4827e8 000e0018 00020002 6e68a380 415c3de0  
06-06 17:09:47.931 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4827f8 00000f35 6e67dc2b 6e529c60 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482808 00000000 00000000 6e75c728 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482818 415c50e0 00000001 000a0019 00050004  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482828 6e68d225 415c3de0 0000094c 6e67c7ac  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482838 6e529ce4 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482848 6e75c745 00000000 415c50e0 00000001  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482858 0002001a 00010002 6e68d225 415c3de0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482868 00000fdb 6e653a37 6e529d60 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d482878 00000000 00000000 6e75c75f 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r3:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736f54 44b4c058 44b57678 44b5a010 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736f64 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736f74 6d5a02e0 6d49d4f8 6d49d5a0 6d5a0b78  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736f84 6d4b6f50 6d4b6f88 6d4ca668 6d4caa98  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736f94 6d4cac58 6d4cac90 6d4cada8 6d4cae88  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736fa4 6d4caec0 6d4caef8 6d4caf30 6d4caf68  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736fb4 6d5a07f0 6d5a0898 6d493880 6d493a10  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736fc4 00000000 6d493b28 00000000 6d4939d0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736fd4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736fe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 6d480098  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71736ff4 6d480140 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71737004 00000000 6d4807d0 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71737014 00000000 6d480a70 6d480aa8 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71737024 00000000 00000000 00000000 6d4815b8  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71737034 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71737044 6d4b43d8 00000000 00000000 6d485730  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r4:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     719081c0 010c0010 00150138 021ee154 08bb021a  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     719081d0 00110008 0702206e 020c0020 0db8031a  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     719081e0 0073206e 020a0032 069e206e 011a0021  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     719081f0 00080a54 206e0011 00100702 0138010c  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908200 e1540015 021a021e 00080a54 206e0011  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908210 00200702 031a020c 206e0db8 00320073  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908220 206e020a 002106a0 08e5011a 00110008  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908230 0702206e 010c0010 000f0138 021ee154  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908240 08e5021a 00110008 0702206e 020c0020  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908250 069f206e 011a0021 000807ef 206e0011  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908260 00100702 0138010c e154000f 021a021e  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908270 000807ef 206e0011 00200702 206e020c  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908280 00210699 0710011a 00110008 0702206e  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     71908290 010c0010 000f0138 021ee154 0710021a  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     719082a0 00110008 0702206e 020c0020 0696206e  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     719082b0 011a0021 00080825 206e0011 00100702  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r5:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4787e0 415db068 44c08160 4181eac8 6d47885c  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4787f0 71907294 6d81fae0 719081e0 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478800 44c08160 44c08e98 00000021 41629cc8  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478810 6e59cbde 00000000 00000001 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478820 00000001 44c08100 44c08970 44c01910  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478830 7190728c 6d820818 44c01cf0 44c08418  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478840 44c08910 44c08160 6d47889c 718ebbe0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478850 6d81fd70 71907294 00000000 44c08160  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478860 44c08970 44c08100 718ebbd2 44c08418  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478870 00000000 44c08910 00000002 000000d7  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478880 44c078f0 44c01cf0 6d478918 718ec494  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d478890 6d810bf0 718ebbe0 00000000 44c078f0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4788a0 44c01cf0 4489bbf0 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4788b0 00000000 718ebae8 00000001 00000001  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4788c0 00000000 44beb908 44beb968 6d478918  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     6d4788d0 718ec458 6d810b80 44beb7c8 44c01cf0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r6:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3878 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3888 00000000 00000800 6d470008 0000045b  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3898 6ecfea94 6d478800 6d81fae0 71733000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f38a8 00000021 415bcd00 bed3a4a8 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f38b8 bed3a4fc 00000001 00000000 41516540  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f38c8 00000000 00000000 6c843870 6d473300  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f38d8 00000000 00000000 00000001 00006000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f38e8 00000000 4005a154 41516540 4151b480  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f38f8 00000000 4151f57c 4151f5f0 4151f4a0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3908 4151f4c0 4151f51c 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3918 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3928 00000000 00000000 00002000 415bb54c  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3938 00000000 00000000 00000006 715f8008  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3948 00000001 00000100 00000200 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3958 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     414f3968 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r7:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000204c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000205c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000206c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000207c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000208c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000209c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     000020ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     000020bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     000020cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     000020dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     000020ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     000020fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000210c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000211c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000212c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     0000213c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near r8:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516520 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516530 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516540 e1f470b2 e207c0ff e088f30c e92d4ff0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516550 e24dd004 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516560 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516570 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516580 e1a01627 e7e30457 e1f470b2 e7952101  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516590 e207c0ff e7852100 e088f30c e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     415165a0 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     415165b0 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     415165c0 e1d410b2 e1a00427 e1f470b4 e7952101  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     415165d0 e207c0ff e7852100 e088f30c e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     415165e0 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     415165f0 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516600 e1d410b4 e1d400b2 e1f470b6 e7952101  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     41516610 e207c0ff e7852100 e088f30c e320f000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near fp:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e6b4 4219e580 41ea9f68 0000001b 415c4e90  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e6c4 00000000 00000001 00000000 4219e580  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e6d4 0000001b 41627a90 00000000 4219e998  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e6e4 4219eb68 4219eb48 00000023 415c50e0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e6f4 00000000 41e21860 eda28924 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e704 00000018 00000000 00000023 415c50e0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e714 00000000 41e1eeb0 9f6253db 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e724 00000013 00000000 00000023 415c50e0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e734 00000000 4219e750 bc282d14 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e744 00000011 00000000 0000003b 415c5950  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e754 00000000 00000011 00000000 0073002f  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e764 006f0074 00610072 00650067 0065002f  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e774 0075006d 0061006c 00650074 00000064  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e784 0000001b 415d3a90 00000000 00000002  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e794 41e14378 00000002 0000001b 415d3a90  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4219e7a4 00000000 00000002 41e0c4b0 00000002  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: memory near sp:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a488 44bcaaf0 00000004 71733038 719081dc  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a498 6d478800 414f3898 0000031a 4151a550  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a4a8 00000926 414f3898 41526ca0 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a4b8 bed3a598 414f3898 bed3a4fc 6d560c28  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a4c8 4219e6d4 41526cf0 2f617661 676e616c  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a4d8 7274532f 3b676e69 41005629 fffffe58  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a4e8 41526ca0 41524388 00000050 41c69008  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a4f8 00000000 6ef31e24 6d478ec4 6d48a6d0  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a508 6e79b000 4219e698 80c0e261 bed3a630  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a518 00000000 bed3a684 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a528 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a538 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a548 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a558 00000000 00000000 414f3898 6d560c28  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a568 415b4c38 00000001 415c42a8 4219e654  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     bed3a578 00000001 415597c1 00000000 00000000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: code around pc:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ad98 e3500000 0a0012e9 eb00132e eafff4bb  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ada8 e795910a e1d020b8 e3590000 0a00134c  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151adb8 e5993000 e5933074 e7930102 eb00124d  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151adc8 e59a1048 e1d020b8 e5913070 e5054008  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151add8 e1520003 2a000008 e5911074 e7910102  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ade8 eb001244 e1a0000a e3a02003 fa012a8a  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151adf8 e3500000 1afffff1 ea0012d0 e5901010  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae08 ea001333 e5963008 e5930000 e3a02001  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae18 fa012a81 e3500000 1afff4d0 ea0012c7  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae28 e5963008 e5930000 e3a02002 fa012a7a  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae38 e3500000 e1d622b8 0a0012c0 e2122901  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae48 0a00122c e59a1000 e3510000 1a001229  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae58 e1a0a000 e1a00006 e1a01004 fa015f03  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae68 e1a0000a ea001223 e795910a e1d020b8  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae78 e3590000 0a00131a e5993000 e5933074  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4151ae88 e7930102 eb00120d e59a1048 e1d020b8  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG: code around lr:
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a8a8 b5106803 e0033b04 3b046804 d0034294  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a8b8 4618428b 2000d2f8 b510bd10 f7ff4604  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a8c8 b160ffef 1f136822 ebc06023 ea5f0c03  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a8d8 d00502ac 00921d01 e882f7cb bd10e000  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a8e8 bd102001 f046b10a 4770bf75 4604b5f8  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a8f8 460d4608 f9c6f7fd 46296922 6960182f  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a908 1a121b7e d8114296 f7ff4632 6965ffeb  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a918 692619ad d01342b5 46314628 1b752201  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a928 ffe0f7ff 1b416920 e0096121 ffdaf7ff  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a938 69636921 1aca4620 463a18a9 ee10f7d9  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a948 bdf84620 43f0e92d 4d2f4691 4a2f460f  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a958 447db08f 58a9461e 4688680c 4604940d  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a968 492bb928 4a2b2005 447a4479 4825e007  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a978 d1074284 20054928 44794a28 f7ca447a  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a988 e034efa0 a8014621 feb6f7fd 68224b24  
06-06 17:09:47.941 288-288/? I/DEBUG:     4154a998 f8d158e9 42a240c4 4922d104 4479a801  
06-06 17:09:48.051 901-27452/? D/ActivityManager: New dropbox entry: android.cit.tu_berlin.de.helloandroid, data_app_native_crash, ce0efb31-f2bc-4170-99ef-d763f06f1b74
06-06 17:09:48.051 901-939/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-06 17:09:48.081 901-1236/? I/ActivityManager: Process android.cit.tu_berlin.de.helloandroid (pid 27371) has died.
06-06 17:09:48.081 901-1236/? W/ActivityManager: Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{4249e058 u0 android.cit.tu_berlin.de.helloandroid/.OSGIService}
06-06 17:09:48.091 2547-27454/? I/CrashMonitor: CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver: Forwarding intent: android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED tag: SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
06-06 17:09:48.091 2547-2547/? I/CrashMonitor: CrashMonitorService: Service started...
06-06 17:09:48.101 291-291/? D/Zygote: Process 27371 terminated by signal (11)
06-06 17:09:48.101 2547-27455/? I/CrashMonitor: CrashMonitorService: action: android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED
06-06 17:09:48.121 2547-27457/? W/CrashMonitor: Imei: Could not get Imei
06-06 17:09:48.161 2547-27457/? W/CrashMonitor: Imei: Could not get Imei
06-06 17:09:48.181 2547-27457/? W/CrashMonitor: Imei: Could not get Imei
06-06 17:09:48.211 188-188/? I/tad: MiscTA Unit 10010: 
06-06 17:09:48.211 188-188/? I/tad: WRITTEN (Size 10)
06-06 17:09:48.231 188-188/? I/tad: Actual erase/write to flash done (count 43, time 1402067388).
06-06 17:09:48.231 188-188/? I/tad: MiscTA: Write of unit 10010 completed - OK
06-06 17:09:48.231 188-188/? I/tad: MiscTA Unit 10009: 
06-06 17:09:48.231 188-188/? I/tad: WRITTEN (Size 11473)
06-06 17:09:48.261 188-188/? I/tad: Actual erase/write to flash done (count 44, time 1402067388).
06-06 17:09:48.261 2547-27457/? I/CrashMonitor: MiscTaStorer: crash data successfully written into MiscTa
06-06 17:09:48.261 188-188/? I/tad: MiscTA: Write of unit 10009 completed - OK
06-06 17:09:48.261 3646-3646/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1512 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.sonymobile.phoneusage.service.plugin.crashstatus.CrashStatusReceiver.onReceiveInternal:31 com.sonymobile.phoneusage.service.DeviceUsageReceiver.onReceive:27 
06-06 17:09:48.271 2547-2547/? I/CrashMonitor: CrashMonitorService: Service stopped...
```

If I only install SCR, I can start all other bundles without an exception. All bundles are in state 'active'. SCR keeps in state 'resolved', logically. Where does this error come from? Definitely is the crash related to starting the SCR. Which relation exists between SCR and the libc.so? Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: **Update 24.08.17**

CRAZY: I tried with an emulator Nexus 4 API 22 Android 5.1 and it works. Since API 21 Dalvik-VM is not used anymore; it's replaced by Android Runtime and it seems that is the reason. In addition Sony is not pure Android, I think - some manufacturer build their "own OS" - at least they modify. So ok, that means I can not use the Sony tablet anymore for my project..